# Java Tutorial Relevance

Tags: java

Ok, so I've decided that I want to learn Java. It's my first more hardcore coding language, because the only other coding I've done is javascript (And I'm still relatively new to that). What I need is a good tutorial, that will assume you have no previous experience in java. I figured that I would take some web tutorials before I bought a book. [This](http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/JavaKid811.pdf) is the tutorial I found. It's a kids one, and I'm only 12, so I figured this would be good for me. My only concern about this tutorial is that it's assuming i'm in older software like windows '98. I'm not sure if I should be concerned that this is outdated or not. Additionally, I would love any other suggestions for java tutorials on windows, as I have to admit that it currently seems quite intimidating :P. I appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: there is a IDE - BlueJ. it's interesting and helps you understand OO concepts. get a book and use internet tutorials along

Comment: +1 BlueJ. Taught Java with that at Uni. You will want to move onto one of Eclipse/IntelliJ/Netbeans later though.

Comment: Thanks, downloading BlueJ right now. I will move on to Eclipse, but I wanted to do a lot of the learning without an environment, so I could really understand how it worked more so, then move on to something like Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I should be concerned that this is outdated or not...

The age of the tutorial would be my first concern, and *Java Programming for Kids, Parents, and Grandparents* is copyright 2004. That's a decent year for a starter Java tutorial, since it will be compatible with the latest version of Java (it just won't cover anything brand new, but you won't need any of that when you're just starting out).

Also, the references to Windows 98 in the document make it sound like they expect the reader to have a newer operating system. Case in point, on page 18 of the PDF we see this:

> If you have an old Windows 98 computer...

So the document is good for anyone with Windows 98, but they assume that Windows 98 is an old computer (the author gives special advice for Win98 users that nobody else needs). The document also references Windows XP, e.g. when the author provides a screenshot from his Windows XP laptop, so the author isn't assuming all readers are using Windows 98.

Ultimately, I wouldn't worry about the age of the document you're reading or references to Windows 98. If it's helping you, keep reading. :)

As for other Java tutorials, I'll defer to the other answers here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the [Oracle/Sun tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/).

Just stay away from the enterprise stuff for now.

*edit: I would like to add that one of the best ways of learning a new language is to try and recreate something simple in that language. This could be a little server which just tells you the current time, a simple tic-tac-toe game, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by enterprise stuff?

Comment: Enterprise stuff in java is the JEE/J2EE "framework". It's basically a whole bunch of frameworks and tools which allow you to develop some advanced (mostly) server concepts. All the enterprise stuff is very overwhelming if youre learning Java for the first time.

Comment: Well, I just started trying Greenfoot, it's kind of cool, and I'm learning the basics. I'm just worried this won't teach me real java.

Comment: Not so sure about Greenfoot. Java is very general purpose, so you could end up primarily writing web server code, games, android apps, etc. You can learn core Java coding from any of these.

Comment: Cool, Greenfoot is just a environment for creating simple java games. Seems to be working, but I'm not sure how advanced the Java I'm using is, and how much it is doing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle actually has a pretty good tutorial on their site (for starting out). I haven't completely gone through their graphics tutorials yet, but it does a pretty good job at covering all the basics, including beginner programming fundamentals for anyone who might be learning it as a first language.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

If you do decide to purchase a book, I have heard good things about the following:
[http://www.amazon.com/Java-How-to-Program/dp/0273759760/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0273759760)

Answer (score 1):

When I learned java I used [Central Connecticut University's introductory course.](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/CS151/cs151java.html) It tends to go slow enough for you to understand but also fast enough to where you don't get bored.

Be sure to do the exercises at the end of the chapters!

Comment: +1 Interesting resource. I personally used the [Berkeley Weiner Lecture Archive](http://wla.berkeley.edu/). But they go pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty good kid's tutorial, even if it is a little outdated. If you get bored with that book and are feeling a little adventurous, I recommend trying [Building Skills in Object-Oriented Design](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/oodesign.html#book-oodesign). The book goes through a complete design of Roulette, Craps and Blackjack. Three games that are complex enough that they can't be trivially designed. Oracle/Sun tutorials are also good, like Steven suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I learn't most of the basics though TheNewBoston. It was clear and was separated into multiple sections. They are video tutorials, I did use more resources to supplement it later on.

Link: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31